# Confusion with probability concepts

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I recently saw this problem-

There are $2$ boxes. 
In the first box, there is just $1$ white ball. 
In the second, there are $2$ black balls and $1$ white ball. 
What is the probability that you draw a white ball?

The solution given is as follows-

There is a $1\over 2$ probability to draw the white ball in the first box.

(This is because there is a $1\over 2$ probability in the first place to draw a ball from Box $1$).

There is a $1\over 2 $$*$$1\over 3$$=$$1\over 6$ 
(Again there is a $1\over 2$ probability to select Box $2$ and $1\over 3$ probability to select a white ball).

Now to compute the total probability we add $1\over 2$ and $1\over 6$ to get the answer $2\over 3$.

Here lies the problem for me. I followed the reasoning for individual boxes but I can't understand why we added the probabilities to get the total probability.

I have read a few articles about when to add probability and not, but I did not understand it as intuitively as property of multiplication in probability.

Please Help!

Comment: Say the question was probability of drawing a black ball. What would the probability be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here lies the problem for me. I followed the reasoning for individual boxes but I can't understand why we added the probabilities to get the total probability.

Let's see the problem with a different (but equivalent) statement.

You toss a fair coin:

1. if T you select from Box 1
2. if H you select from Box 2.

One of the two events must happen, both with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ thus to calculate the total probability you have to sum the two probabilities of the individual boxes:

$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\times 1}_{\text{Event 1}}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3}}_{\text{Event 2}}$$

3. To complete the experiment, a third different event can happen: the coin tosses H and you get a Black ball. Probability $\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{6}$

Why we have to sum these probability? because these events describe all that can happen, they are disjointed and thus (if we calculated their probability correctly) their probability sum mus be 1. (100%)

Let's check

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{6}=1$$

we are all set.

Answer (score 1):

> Here lies the problem for me. I followed the reasoning for individual boxes but I can't understand why we added the probabilities to get the total probability.

Alternate problem.
You are going to throw a single die.
You are trying to compute the probability of throwing a 1, 2, or 3.

The die has 6 numbers that might come up.

Therefore, the chance of throwing a 1 is $\frac{1}{6}.$

Similarly, the chance of throwing a 2 is $\frac{1}{6}.$

Similarly, the chance of throwing a 3 is $\frac{1}{6}.$

Therefore, the chance of throwing a 1 **or** a 2 **or** a **3** is

$$\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{3}{6}.$$